# CSS issue with top margin in safari

Tags: css, safari, margin

I can't get a top margin to show in safari. CSS works fine and the #divcontainer has a top margin and is centered in firefox and other browsers but not in safari.

I would like a 10px space to show above the container which will hold all other content.

Here is the CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */

body {

    color: #000000; /*This sets all text to Black*/
    /*background-color: #FFFFFF; /*This sets the bacground to white*/
    margin: 100px auto; /*This sets the margin to zero*/
    padding:0;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
p {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000099;
}
h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000099;
}
h3 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000099;
}
.redtext {
    color: #FF0000;
}
a {
    color: #009900;
}
a:link {
    color: #000099;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:visited {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;

}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;

}

.menu {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
}
.menu a:link {
    color: #336600;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:visited {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #990000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:active {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div#container {
    width: 960px;
    height:760;
    overflow:auto;
    /*margin-left:0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */

}
div#outer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}
div#header {
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
div#nav {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    position:relative;
}
div#main {
    position:relative;
    width: auto;
}
div#footer {
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
}#nav {
    position: relative;
    padding:20px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: could you also post the html?

Comment: You'll also need 'px' after the 760 in div#container's height, though I would recommend against trying to dictate height as a general rule.

Comment: <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyENSO_Main.css" />
<title>New Site</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--

-->
</style></head>

<body>

<div class="container">  

<!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: In this HTML, container is a class.  You refer to it as an Id in your css

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to set the margin: 10px auto; on the #container.  Usually, I do this:

```
body {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  height: 760px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

...assuming the #container div is the first element, that should work out.

You may also want to try out one of the css reset files out there.

Comment: The html is underdeveloped I am trying to just get the main container to show up properly and go from there here is the html